# Por que dá erro nesse tipo de comparação/escolha?

Tags: portugol, visualg

```
escreval("Digite o consumo")
   leia(consumo)
   escolha consumo
   caso <= 100
      escreval("Parabéns, voce e economico")
   caso >=101 e <200
      escreval("Cuidado com o consumo")
   caso >200
      escreval("Consumo execessivo")
   outrocaso
      escreval("Valor invalido")
   fimescolha
```

Comment: Não pode. A estrutura do `escolha/caso` irá verificar se `consumo` é igual ao valor definido em cada caso. Basicamente você estaria comparando `consumo = <= 100`, o que não faz sentido.

Comment: Então so posso ter apenas um valor definido para o "caso"?

Comment: @JoãoVictorTrindade tenta ver a resposta aí embaixo para ver se consegui te ajudar...

Answer (score 0):

Para seu programa dar certo nesse jeito tem que ser por estrutura condicional `se`:

```
escreval("Digite o consumo")
   leia(consumo)
   se consumo  <= 100 e consumo>=0 entao

      escreval("Parabéns, voce e economico")
   fimse
   se consumo>=101 e  consumo<200 entao
      escreval("Cuidado com o consumo")
   fimse
   se consumo >=200  entao
      escreval("Consumo execessivo")
   fimse
      se consumo <0 entao
      escreval("Valor invalido")
   fimse
```

Caso opte por realizar `escolha/caso` você tem que lembrar que esse tipo de estrutura é como `switch/case` nas outras linguagens. Tens que ter um número ou caracter definido para poder realizar o caso. Exemplo caso 105 ... caso 200... (pré define os números que poderão ser os de acesso ao caso) no exemplo que você deu é como se fosse uma comparação, se consumo for <100 faça ...(Lembrando que <100 iria ter vários "números" por isso não pode ser utilizado `escolha/caso`)